# by jquery, set to option of html-select element selected atribude by text, not value

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a select element.

```
<select class='cSelectType'>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
        <option value="4">four</option>
        <option value="5">five</option>
</select>
```

i can by jquery set option value selected like this:

```
$('.cSelectType option[value=4]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

And select element will show "Four". By i wont something like this:

```
$('.cSelectType option[xxx=Four]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

i.e By text set selected attribute.

some ideas please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) filter:

> **Description:** Select all elements that contain the specified text.

```
$(".cSelectType option:contains('four')").attr('selected', 'selected');
```