# jquery option text selector problem

Tags: jquery

```
<select id="name">
 <option value="1005">peter</option>
 <option value="2056" selected="selected">shan</option>
</select>
```

how to set option's text=peter selected?
like this `$('#name option[text=peter]').attr('selected',true)`;

Comment: possible duplicate of [by jquery, set to option of html-select element selected atribude by text, not value ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433442/by-jquery-set-to-option-of-html-select-element-selected-atribude-by-text-not-va)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("#name option[value='1005']").attr('selected','selected');
```

Comment: @BRAVO, I'd suggest using `...attr('selected', true);` rather than `'selected','selected'` but this **does** (or **should**) work. [Demo at: JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Chtdk/).

Answer (score 0):

also

```
$("#name option[text=peter]").attr("checked", "checked");
```

works.

Comment: It should be  $("#name option[text=peter]").attr("selected", "selected"); as it is a select box                                  other option is $("#name option:contains('peter')").attr('selected', 'selected');

Comment: you are right actually but ("checked", "checked") also works.